# Map alt domain to specific section of website w/o MU

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules, domain-mapping

I have one website on which I want to use multiple domain names.

The URL pattern on the existing looks like this:

```
 Main domain: - shop.com
              - shop.com/products
              - shop.com/about-us

              - shop.com/pools/
              - shop.com/pools/products
              - shop.com/pools/about-us

              - shop.com/spas/
              - shop.com/spas/products
              - shop.com/spas/about-us
```

I'd like to use multiple domain so I could use:

```
 Main domain: - shop.com
              - shop.com/products
              - shop.com/about-us

Other domain: - pools.com (showing shop.com/pools)
              - pools.com/products (showing shop.com/pools/products)
              - pools.com/about-us (showing shop.com/pools/about-us)

Other domain: - spas.com (showing shop.com/spas)
              - spas.com/products (showing shop.com/spas/products)
              - spas.com/about-us (showing shop.com/spas/about-us)
```

**I don't want to use Multisite/Network provided by WordPress.**

Obselete plugin that was apparently doing what I want:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/domain-mapping-system/

Similar questions:
[Custom domain for sub-section of parent website](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82980/custom-domain-for-sub-section-of-parent-website)

Interesting question somewhat related but not exactly applicable for me:
[Multiple Domain Names - One WP Install (non-Multisite) - Default Each Domain name to Category Archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14837/multiple-domain-names-one-wp-install-non-multisite-default-each-domain-nam?rq=1)

Thank you very much for you help!